# # of possible binary string arrangements given constraint

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Consider a random binary string where each bit can be set to 1 with probability $p$.

Let $Z[x,y]$ denote the number of arrangements of a binary string of length $x$ and the $x$-th bit is set to 1. Moreover, $y$ bits are set 1 including the $x$-th bit and there are no runs of $k$ consecutive zeroes.

If for some $m$, I'm given $Z[x,y]$ for all $1 \leq x \leq c$, where $c$ represents length of string, and all $1\leq y \leq m$. And I want to compute the number of strings with exactly $m$ ones and no run of $k$ consecutive zeroes.

The best I'm able to do with this is just set discrete values for each of these parameters and enumerate it that way. But I'm not able to combinatorically resolve the numbers.

I've worked out that the probability of a string of length $c$ with exactly $m$ ones is $$p^m {c \choose m}(1-p)^{c-m}{c \choose c-m}$$

How do I proceed?

Comment: You need to clarify the original statement.  You have set to $1$ with probability p.  What happens with probability 1-p?  Is it set to $0$ or just left as is?

Comment: It's a random binary string, so for each bit, it's either 0 with probability 1-p or 1 with probability p